# Why do bubbles lose their shimmer when touched by the wand?

Tags: optics, bubbles

I was playing with bubbles and noticed that bubbles that shimmer due to thin film interference tend to lose their colour when touched by a wand. When once again released they do not regain their colour.[Here is a video I took with my phone.](https://youtu.be/hl3o7jSWc6E)

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

When the soap bubble touches another surface it looses material and becomes thinner. The color effects are dependent on film thickness and disappear.

Comment: Is there a reason for it losing material?